# The prefix "xs" for element "xs:schema" is not bound

Tags: xsd-validation

Following is the xsd that i am trying to use while generating a client for SOAP Service, Eclipse is throwing an error : The prefix "xs" for element "xs:schema" is not bound.

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" 
           targetNamespace="bdo.com.ph/RemitAPI">
  <xs:element name="CheckServiceResponse" 
              nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="apiRequest" nillable="true" type="tns:APIRequest"/>
  .............................
      <xs:element name="referenceNo" type="xs:string" form="qualified"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I got this xsd from a webservice

Comment: Have you just extracted the Schema part from the WSDL? Probably the xs namespace is defined in the envelope of the WSDL. Try adding xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" as an attribute in your schema element: <xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="bdo.com.ph/RemitAPI" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

Comment: that worked that worked :) . yes i extracted the schema from WSDL. thanks for that instant help.
But now I am facing the next issue here:
when trying to generate client from a soap web service

java.io.IOException: Element {http://www.bdo.com.ph/RemitAPI}apiStatusRequest is referenced but not defined.

Comment: Please, add code to the question, not the comments.

Comment: Kimi .. that's done, at first i didn't get how to add code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

was not added in the Schema XSD.
adding it made me proceed to the next step.

```
xmlns:tns="http://www.bdo.com.ph/RemitAPI
```

was not there in the XSD, though it was present in the enclosing WSDL.

When extracting an XSD from a WSDL to local machine, the namespace references in the XSD do not get picked up from the WSDL, they need to be declared in the XSD.

Answer (score 2):

This happens mainly because of the missing namespacedeclaration.

```
   "<elem "namespace" ..xsi:nil=true.>"
```

will work. Basically the XML validator expects a namespace to validate against.