# Java XML against XSD: The prefix "xs" for element "xs:schema" is not bound

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, against

I have trouble with my validation and I can't find any solutions.
I am validating an XML file against this. XSD with my own Java 9 program which throws an Exception with the error message

```
The prefix "xs" for element "xs:schema" is not bound.
```

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="vDiPE">
    <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="itemIn"/>
                    <xs:element name="itemCo"/>
                    <xs:element name="exitcon" cid="xs:integer" />
                    <xs:element name="condition">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequenece>
                                            <xs:element name="if" />
                                            <xs:element name="then" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="">
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="texPath" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" default="Unnamed Item" />
            <xs:attribute name="positionX" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="positionY" type="xs:integer" use="required" />

            <xs:attribute name="draw" type="xs:boolean" default="true" />
            <xs:attribute name="hitbox" type="xs:boolean" default="false" />
            <xs:attribute name="collidable" type="xs:boolean" default="false" />

            <xs:attribute name="hintgiving" type="xs:boolean" default="false" />

            <xs:attribute name="used" type="xs:boolean" default="false" />
    </xs:complexType>
```

What is wrong? I researched a much but nothing fixed the issue :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The prefix "xs" for element "xs:schema" is not bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609971/the-prefix-xs-for-element-xsschema-is-not-bound)

Comment: Clearly the prefix "xs" is bound in the code you have shown us. So the error must mean that it isn't bound in some other code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: I note the typo "xs:sequenece" which strongly suggests to me that the code you have posted is not the code you were running.

Comment: I added the xmlns:xs="..." (from the duplicate link) but when I try to construct the xml from the classes generated by the using a JAXB Marshaller, there's an unnecessary xmlns="..." attribute in the xml.